# Can connect with LDAP ActiveDirectory?

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ldap, openldap, rt

good to everyone.

You see, I'm trying to configure 'Request tracker' ticketing program, next to active directory.

But I have a problem, I can't make the connection from Ubuntu to Windows, the active directory doesn't even give a signal.

I am trying the anonymous and credentialed ldapsearch and neither works.
I have tried to remove the firewall from the active directory and it doesn't work either.

I have tried this command to enter anonymously.

`ldapsearch -x -H ldap://"IP_ActiveDirectory" -b "dc=xxxx,dc=com"`

with answer

`In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed.... data 0, v4563`

and with credentials

`ldapsearch -x -b "dc=xxxx,dc=com" -H "ldap://"IP_ActiveDirectory" -D "CN=admin,DC=xxxxx,DC=com" -W`

with answer

`Invalid credentials (49) .... data 52e, v4563`

I don't know if I have some wrong parameter, if I need to activate / deactivate something in Active directory or ubuntu.
I know the credentials are correct because I just created them and with a generic password.

I'm in the same range of IP's, I have tried to also put the DNS and always the same errors.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://serverdc.example.com:636 -x -D "adminguy@example.com" -W -b "DC=example,DC=com" -s sub -a always
```

Comment: It really works, at least I don't get any errors.
That yes, I get a lot of information, I imagine that in short, at least you can see my Active Directory and confirm the connection, right?

Thanks.